# Parser grammar for these expresisons

Tags: java, antlr

I am trying to come up with a simple EBNF grammar for parsing the below expressions
examples: ("->" isn't part of input). 'a', 'b' 'c' are multi character words which contain alphabets only.

```
-> a
-> (a)
-> (a | b | c)
-> (a (b | c | d))
-> (a (b | (c | d)) )
-> (a (
     b (
        c x
      | d (e | f)
      )
    )
  )
```

I tried coming up with several grammars (in Antlr) but all of them break for a few cases, this is what I have right now, Any help would be appreciated.

```
term:   '(' WORD+ options_list ')' 
    |   '(' WORD+ ('|' term)* ')'
    |   WORD+
    ;

options_list:   '(' term ('|' term)* ')' 
    ;
}

WORD    :   ('a'..'z')+ 
    ;
```

**EDIT 1:** 
Basically I am trying to create a hierarchical tree of words from the grammar for example in the last case the tree would look like these

```
     [a]
      |
     [b]
     / \
 [c,x]  [d]
        /  \
       [e]  [f]
```

I don't want depend on Antlr or JavaCC for auto generating the parser for a different set of reasons, I would want to write my own simple recursive descent parser in order to do that I am first coming up with a valid grammar that works for all cases, then it would simple enough to implement from that.

**EDIT2:**
After working some bits I have this which seems to work for

```
term:   WORD term?
    |   '(' term ('|' term)* ')'
    ;


WORD    :   ('a'..'z')+ 
    ;
```

Comment: I would look at JavaCC or tools which do this already. You can read their documentation and source to see how they do it.

Comment: What are the intended tokens in `c x | d (e | f)`?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am using Antlr to verify my grammar.

Comment: In that case; what is the question?

Comment: @Raffaele Sorry for being unclear, the only tokens are '(' & ')' rest all alphanumeric characters. I have updated grammer.

Comment: @jack_carver Are `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. single words, or a list of words? I assume, from your examples, that these are single words, in which case you shouldn't be using `WORD+`. The rule `WORD` already matches an entire word as is.

Comment: a, b, c are multi character words which contain alphabets only

Comment: @jack_carver Are the following expressions valid? `a b c` (no parentheses); `a | b` (no parentheses).

Comment: a b c would be valid, but a | b wouldn't

Answer (score 1):

The following grammar appears to parse all your provided examples.

```
term        : WORD+
            | '(' alt_term ')'
            ;

alt_term    : app_term
            | app_term '|' alt_term
            | app_term '|' '(' alt_term ')'
            ;

app_term    : WORD+
            | WORD+ '(' alt_term ')'
            ;

WORD        : ('a'..'z')+ 
            ;
```

I tested it in AntlrWorks, and all of your examples are parsed. I just added `EOF` recognition and `skip` on whitespaces.

Analysis of each case:

1. `a`

   1.1. `term` (1)
2. `(a)`

   2.1. `term` (2)

   2.2. `alt_term` (1)

   2.3. `app_term` (1)
3. `(a | b | c)`

   3.1. `term` (2)

   3.2. `alt_term` (2)

   3.3. `app_term` (1)

   3.4. `alt_term` (2)

   3.5. `app_term` (1)

   3.6. `alt_term` (1)

   3.7. `app_term` (1)
4. `(a (b | c | d))`

   4.1. `term` (2)

   4.2. `alt_term` (1)

   4.3. `app_term` (2)

   4.4. `alt_term` (2)

   4.5. `app_term` (1)

   4.6. `alt_term` (2)

   4.7. `app_term` (1)

   4.8. `alt_term` (1)

   4.9. `app_term` (1)
5. `(a (b | (c | d)) )`

   5.1. `term` (2)

   5.2. `alt_term` (1)

   5.3. `app_term` (2)

   5.4. `alt_term` (3)

   5.5. `app_term` (1)

   5.6. `alt_term` (2)

   5.7. `app_term` (1)

   5.8. `alt_term` (1)

   5.9. `app_term` (1)
6. `(a (b (c x | d (e | f))))`

   6.1. `term` (2)

   6.2. `alt_term` (1)

   6.3. `app_term` (2)

   6.4. `alt_term` (1)

   6.5. `app_term` (2)

   6.6. `alt_term` (2)

   6.7. `app_term` (1)

   6.8. `alt_term` (1)

   6.9. `app_term` (2)

   6.10. `alt_term` (2)

   6.11. `app_term` (1)

   6.12. `alt_term` (1)

   6.13. `app_term` (1)